# Request body too large

Tags: servicestack, iis-express

When I try to upload a 80mb file from postman to my local endpoint running in Visual Studio 2019 on IISExpress I get the following error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

So I added this to applicationhost.config for the project:

```xml
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1050000" /> 
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
```

This stop the error coming when I make the API request but now I just get a ServiceStack generated "snapshot" page telling me how long request took and the date but my actual endpoint is never hit.

Inside my logs I can see ServiceStack throwing this exception:

> 2020-07-20 01:57:56.0497||ERROR|ServiceStackHost|Request body too
> large. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.BadHttpRequestException:
> Request body too large.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason
> reason)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.InitializeRequestIO()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1
> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.EnsureBufferedAsync(Int32
> minCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream
> stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()    at
> ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.get_FormData() in
> C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\NetCore\NetCoreRequest.cs:line
> 167    at
> ServiceStack.HttpRequestExtensions.GetFlattenedRequestParams(IRequest
> request) in
> C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\HttpRequestExtensions.cs:line
> 555    at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequestAsync(IRequest
> httpReq, IRestPath restPath) in
> C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\RestHandler.cs:line
> 132    at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest
> req, IResponse httpRes, String operationName) in
> C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\RestHandler.cs:line
> 89|url: |action:

So the Body length still needs to be set somewhere but everywhere I look points back to the config I have already used.

Is there additional setting required or is this a ServiceStack issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was missing this option in startup:

```cs
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 30 MB
});
```

Comment: `MaxRequestBodySize` is type of long, so `long.MaxValue` might be preferable, as int limit is around 2GB in some cases